# How to call vscode-nls using require function

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am developing a VSCode extension application and I am trying to import `vscode-nls` using the `require` function but it is not working. What do I have to do in order to get it working?

The **extension.js** currently looks like:

```
const nls = require('vscode-nls');
let localize = nls.loadMessageBundle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do run the following command to install vscode-nls before import.

> npm install vscode-nls --save